obtener resultados de una URL con Json
intento obtener datos de una URL que manda unos datos JSON.
https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/13/municipios/13085
por lo que entiendo, no estoy leyendo bien el JSON, ya que no obtengo resultados..
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/13/municipios/13071",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) { 
  datos= data.current;
   document.getElementById("Temperatura").value=datos.temperatura_actual;
   document.getElementById("Humedad").value=datos.humedad;
   document.getElementById("procio").value=datos.viento;

   },

         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert(errorThrown);
          }
});

alguna sugerencia..'??
Gracias...

No se usar JQuery, pero simplemente imprimiendo data dentro de la propiedad success podes darte cuenta de que la propiedad current no existe, el parametro data ya te da todo lo que necesitas.
Según la documentación de JQuery, el tipo de dato que se traiga del servidor será formateado dependiendo del tipo definido en la propiedad datatype, así que el JSON será pasado a objeto de JavaScript, no te tenés que preocupar por eso.


$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://www.el-tiempo.net/api/json/v2/provincias/13/municipios/13071",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById("Temperatura").value = data.temperatura_actual;
    document.getElementById("Humedad").value = data.humedad;
    document.getElementById("procio").value = data.viento;
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="header"></h1>
    <input type="text" id="Temperatura" />
    <input type="text" id="Humedad" />
    <input type="text" id="procio" />



